# QML Bluetooth chat

Tags: qt, bluetooth, qml

I'm having a hard time understanding the QML Bluetooth module.
This is my code:

```
BluetoothDiscoveryModel {
    id: btModel
    running: false
    discoveryMode: BluetoothDiscoveryModel.MinimalServiceDiscovery
    onServiceDiscovered: {
        if (serviceFound)
            return
        serviceFound = true

        console.log(service.deviceName + " " + service.serviceName);
        remoteDeviceName = service.deviceName
        socket.setService(service)
    }
}
BluetoothSocket {
    id: socket
    connected: true

    onSocketStateChanged: {
        switch (socketState) {
            case BluetoothSocket.Unconnected:
                ...
                break;
            case BluetoothSocket.NoServiceSet:
                ...
                break;
            case BluetoothSocket.Connected:
                ...
                break;
            case BluetoothSocket.Connecting:
                ...
                break;
            case BluetoothSocket.ServiceLookup:
                ...
                break;
            case BluetoothSocket.Closing:
                ...
                break;
            case BluetoothSocket.Listening:
                ...
                break;
            case BluetoothSocket.Bound:
                ...
                break;
        }
    }

   onStringDataChanged: {
        var data = socket.stringData;
        data = data.substring(0, data.indexOf('\n'))
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

This allows me to connect to my phone, but the service name is "Headset Gateway".
I need to create a simple chat, and I don't know if it is possible to communicate between my phone and my pc with this service.

I'm using an app called Bluetooth Terminal to test the connection and to send strings to the program, but I get an error when connecting in the app "Connection failed: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1".

Comment: @ukBaz And what is the difference between client and server in a Bluetooth type communication?

Comment: That's not really client-server architecture. BT devices surrounding you can provide services that you can use. You should use [BluetoothService](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtbluetooth-bluetoothservice.html) to discover such devices and the to communicate with them using [BluetoothSocket](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtbluetooth-bluetoothsocket.html). [detailsChanged()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtbluetooth-bluetoothservice.html#detailsChanged-signal) will be fired for each device. Only `Rfcomm` and `L2cap` protocols are supported so you need is to run an appropriate service on a remote device.

Comment: I see you set no [service](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtbluetooth-bluetoothsocket.html#service-prop) to the BluetoothSocket

Comment: I've set the service in the BluetoothDiscoveryModel.

Comment: There is no `BluetoothSocket.setService` function, you should use `socket.service = service` instead.

Comment: Changed, but if i try with my pc to connect to my phone i get nothing. I'm using the uuid filer and using the same uuid generated online.